# how to get number of user in a group from active directory

Tags: c#-4.0

I am trying to get number of user from a particular group?so how can i achieve?

[image]

Comment: You can post code here too, adding it as screenshot makes it harder to go through/reference.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same approach, you did with groups ... Please find an example below.Add any properties like givenname, sn etc...

```
foreach(var group in froups){
    DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de, "(objectClass=person)");
        ds.Filter = "(memberOf=CN=" + group + ",OU=Distribution Groups,DC=" + domain + ",DC=com)";
    }
```